# How to apply a full word search in Qna maker?

Tags: c#, asp.net, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I have bot made using bot framework V4 using c#. It has luis and qnamaker used in combination. I am facing problem with qnamaker as does not do a full word search. If I type "**deepak**", it gets answer from qna maker having a word "**deep**".
[image]

But in this kind of situation, it should return no answer in qnamaker. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: I am not sure how you have set up your KB. However, I tried using similar utterances on my end and it is predicting as expected. If you are still experiencing the issue, I would recommend making use of [metadata tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/metadata-generateanswer-usage#use-metadata-to-filter-answers-by-custom-metadata-tags).